# Find next closest date

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have some dates which are currently stored as a list of strings.

For example:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>();
dates.Add("1/10/14");
dates.Add("2/9/14");
dates.Add("1/15/14");
dates.Add("2/3/14");
dates.Add("2/15/14");
```

(The date is in `mm/dd/yy` format)

I will take a user's input (also in `mm/dd/yy` format), but as a string.

Now, I want to find the date in the array that is the next closest after the user input date.

For example, if the user enters `"1/13/14"`, the output should be `"1/15/14"`.
If the user enters `"2/5/14"`, then the next closest date is `"2/9/14"`.
But if the user enter a date that is later than the last date (say `"3/1/14"`, it will STILL return the last date in the array which is `"2/15/14"`)

I know at some point you have to convert to type DateTime, but I couldn't figure out the logic to find such date.

Comment: Parsing strings to dates is an entirely separate problem from finding the nearest date in a list of dates.  Handle them separatly.  First handle parsing these dates into `DateTime` object.  Then, once you have that, work on finding the nearest date in a `List<DateTime>`.

Comment: `mm` for minutes, `M` or `MM` for months by the way..

Comment: Why are you storing the dates as strings in the first place?

Comment: Those dates were stored as text in a text file.

Comment: @user3320572 So then parse them into `DateTime` objects.  That they come from a file shouldn't be relevant when trying to solve the problem of finding the nearest date.

Comment: I know it is not very difficult to convert string to datetime, but I have decided to show the original data. Perhaps someone knows a better way to solve it without parsing to datetime.

Comment: Consider this: If you want the "next" date, that date has to be greater than the one you have. Then, when you've found all the dates that are greater than the one you have, you want the smallest one of those. A naive implementation using LINQ (assuming the list contains DateTime's and not strings): `dates.Where(dt => dt > theOneIHave).Min()`. Now, if you have a lot of dates, first grabbing all those larger, and then retrieving the smallest, might not perform very well. In this case I would probably sort the list, and then use a binary search to find the nearest (but greater) value.

Comment: Now, note that I interpreted "next" as in "next date value in ascending order", not as "next in the list". I say this because it doesn't look like the list has been sorted.

Comment: @user3320572 do you want the answer to be the actual closest date, or the closest date without going over? For example, do you want "1/14/14" to return "1/15/14" or "1/10/14"?

Comment: @Gray THe closest date AFTER the user input date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>();
            dates.Add("1/10/14");
            dates.Add("2/9/14");
            dates.Add("1/15/14");
            dates.Add("2/3/14");
            dates.Add("2/15/14");

            var allDates = dates.Select(DateTime.Parse).OrderBy(d=>d).ToList();
            var inputDate = DateTime.Parse("1/13/14");

            var closestDate = inputDate >= allDates.Last()
                ? allDates.Last()
                : inputDate <= allDates.First()
                    ? allDates.First()
                    : allDates.First(d => d >= inputDate);
```

For now I'm just parsing strings, but you should handle it separately. This is simple plain LINQ, you can go fancy and do binary search as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that uses a **Binary Search**.

You need to have a list of `DateTime`s, no question about it. No point in keeping them as `string`s, parse them on the way into the list if you have to. You can use LINQ to convert all the elements in the list, but that's the only way you'll be able to compare dates with eachother.

Check out the page for [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to understand why I am using the bitwise operator on the return value.

```
//build list of random dates
Random r = new Random();
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dates.Add(new DateTime(2014, r.Next(1,13), r.Next(1,28)));
}

//sort list (if you don't do this, you'll most likely get the wrong answer)
dates.Sort();

//get input
string input = "1/13/14";
DateTime inputDate = DateTime.Parse(input);

//find nearest
var result = dates.BinarySearch(inputDate);
DateTime nearest;

//get match or next in list.
if(result >= 0)
    nearest = dates[result];
else if (~result == dates.Count )
    nearest =dates.Last();
else
    nearest = dates[~result];
```

#### If you need to find the true closest, use this in place of the last `if` block.

```
//get match, or true nearest date in list
if(result >= 0)                   //date was found! Use that index.
    nearest = dates[result];
else if (~result == 0)            //date not found, smaller than any item in the list. use first index.
    nearest = dates.First();
else if(~result == dates.Count)   //date was not found, and is greater than all items. Use last index.
    nearest = dates.Last();
else                              //date not found, somewhere in the middle of the list. find the nearest date                              
{
    var daysAfter = dates[~result].Subtract(inputDate);      //date after input
    var daysBefore = inputDate.Subtract(dates[~result - 1]); //date before input
    if(daysAfter < daysBefore)
        nearest = dates[~result];
    else
        nearest = dates[~result - 1];
}
```

Comment: The question seems to ask for "next higher", not "nearest". That would mean you only have to guard `~result` for `>= Count`.

Comment: Oh, I completely overlooked that. Thank you. I even made a comment on someone else's code. D'oh!

Comment: I didn't see one, but I added my own. Probably the same as what you were gonna do. Go ahead and edit if it is superior though. This makes the problem a lot easier (not to mention more efficient).

Comment: This one will fail for a targetdate later then the latest array value. (~result == Count).

Comment: Just noticed that as you posted, should be good now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime searchDate = new DateTime(2014,03,01);

var orderedDates = dates
.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "M/d/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
.OrderBy(d => d).ToList();

var result = orderedDates.FirstOrDefault(d => d > searchDate);
if (result == default(DateTime))
  result = orderedDates.Last();
```

Comment: This works for Price Is Right rules (closest without going over), but it doesn't find the true closest, right?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
List<string> dates   = YourListOfStringsHere() ; // list of strings in MM/dd/yyyy form.
DateTime desiredDate = new DateTime(2014,2,27) ;
DateTime foundDate   = dates
                       .Select( x => DateTime.ParseExact(x,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                       .Where( x => x >= desiredDate.Date )
                       .Min()
                       ;
```

Why you'd be storing date/time values as a string is beyond me. When you load them, why not convert them? That way, they're easier to manipulate, you know you've got clean data. Everything becomes much simpler.